# Configure NTLM (Windows Authentication) for a SOAP ServiceReference

Tags: c#, asp.net, soap, ntlm, service-reference

I'm getting this error in my program:

```
The HTTP request is unauthorized with client authentication scheme 'Anonymous'. The authentication header received from the server was 'Negotiate,NTLM'.
```

What i understood from it (and from how my program works) was that i need to pass my windows credentials (NTLM) to the SOAP protocol, because my website doesn't allow Anonymous users.

What i need is to put somewhere that SOAP uses NTLM. Maybe i wasn't clear enough, Sorry.

Thanks.